# Need to share the password between two apps in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to share the password between two Apps in Android.

Can I use the Explicit intent?

How secure is the explicit intent? Are there any ways by which explicit intent can be hacked ?

Regards,

Sameer Joshi

Comment: BroadCastReceiver also can be a  good idea

Comment: use Encryption then send and receive via `BroadCastReceiver`

Comment: use implicit intent instead of explicit

Answer (score 0):

The best way I believe you should use a server to store and retrieve the information, you can use Firebase's Firestore with a secure authentication.
If you need it between apps you can use a **Service** with [Android Interface Definition Language (AIDL)](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl) with a query for Android 11 (API level 30)

```
<manifest package="com.example.app">
  <queries>
    <!-- Specific apps you interact with, eg: -->
    <package android:name="com.example.service" />
  </queries>
  ...
</manifest>
```